# Is it possible to delete everything to the right of the cursor in Iterm2 if cursor is in the middle of the line?

Tags: terminal, hotkeys, iterm2, keymapping, forward-delete

Is it possible to delete everything to the right of the cursor in a terminal session i.e. Iterm2? I am specifically looking for a key mapping like there is to delete an entire line with ⌘←Del or one word with ⌥←del

For example:

```
$ This is example code | I want everything on the right of the pipe deleted if the cursor started at the pipe
```

I've tried looking for hex codes and adjusting the profiles in Iterm2's global setting and found nothing so far.